# Show a modal with receipt after submit form (Codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

**My target is, after I submit the form, there'll be a modal after reload that shows the transaction details.** I have made a next page transaction details, however, it is much better to do the receipt php on **onload modal** after submission. But I don't know how to start. I provided a screenshot below of my current work. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

[image]

**View:**

```
<button type="button" data-id="<?php echo $rows->userID; ?>"  data-firstname="<?php echo $rows->firstname; ?>" class=" showmodal btn btn-success btn-sm text-bold "   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fundModal"><i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd mr-1"></i> FUND </button> // This button shows modal when clicked



//This is my modal for transferring fund
  <div class="modal fade" id="fundModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog " role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header bg-green">
                    <h5 class="modal-title text-bold" id="exampleModalLabel">Fund</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-body bg-white text-center">
                        <label><h3>Transfer fund:</h3></label>
                       <br>
                    
  <!-- FORM -->
                    <div id="errorMessage" style="color: red; display: none; font-size: 11px"></div>
                    
                        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('network/form_validation');?>">    
                         <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 100%" >
                             <input type="hidden" id="usertransferid" name="userID">
                             <input type="hidden" id="firstname" name="receiptname" value="<?php echo $rows->firstname; ?>">
                                    
                                <div class="col-lg-12" >    
                            
                             
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Amount" name="amount" autocomplete="new-amount" value="" class="form-control number" id="box"  >  
                                    
                                    <br>
                                    
                                    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('warning'); ?>
            
          
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" autocomplete="new-password"  name="fundpass" class="form-control"  id="password" required ">    
                                    
                                    <br> 
                                    
                  
                                    <!--  buttons -->
        
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-bold" name="save" id="insert" value="Transfer">
                                
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </form> 
                             </div>
                          
                      
             </div>
        </div>
                
        </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
 public function form_validation()
        
{
        
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("amount","Amount", 'required|numeric');
    
                    $this->load->library('form_validation');
                    
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fundpass', 'fundpass', 'callback_password_check');
                   
                
                    if($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
                        
                        
                       
                        echo '<script>alert("Invalid input of Password!");</script>';
                        redirect('network/agents', 'refresh');
                        
                    }
                    else {
                     
                        if($this->form_validation->run())
                        {
                            

                            
                            $ref= $this->session->userdata('uid') + time ();
                            $id = $this->input->post('userID');
                            $fname = $this->input->post('receiptname');
                            $pData = array(
                                'userID' => $id,
                                'transactionSource' => 'FR',
                                'refNumber' => 'FI' . $ref,
                                "amount" =>$this->input->post("amount"),
                                "transType" =>"in",  
                            );
                            
                            $this->networks->fundin($pData);
                            
                            
                            $ref= $this->session->userdata('userID') + time ();
                            
                            $data1 = array(
                                'userID' => $this->session->userdata('uid'),
                                "transactionSource" => 'FR',
                                "refNumber" => 'FO' . $ref,
                                "amount" =>$this->input->post("amount"),
                                "transType" =>"out",

                            );
                            
                            
                            $this->networks->insert_data($data1);
                            
//                             return json_encode($data1);

                            $_SESSION["amount"] = $this->input->post("amount");
                            $_SESSION["receivedID"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["receiptFName"] = $fname;
                            $_SESSION["reference"] =  $this->input->post("refNumber");
                            
                            redirect(base_url() . "network/receipt");
                           
                            
                        
                       }
                        else
                        {
                            $this->index();
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                    
}
public function password_check($fundpass)
{
    $id = $this->session->userdata('uid');
    
    if($this->session->userdata('password')!== md5($fundpass)) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('password_check', 'The {field} does not match');
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

**Model:**

```
    function fundin($data)
    {
       
        // Fund in
        
        $id = $this->input->post('userID');
        $sqlInsertLedger = "INSERT INTO transaction_ledger (transactionSource, transType, refNumber, userID, amount, currentBalance, previousBalance, remarks, createdBy)
                                select '".$data['transactionSource']."', '".$data['transType']."', '".$data['refNumber']."', ".$data['userID'].", ".$data['amount'].", sum(TU.currentPoints + ".$data['amount'].") as totalPoints, TU.currentPoints,
                                'funded by agent', '".$this->session->userdata('uid')."'
                                from users TU where TU.userID=?";
        
        $Q = $this->db->query($sqlInsertLedger, $data['userID']);
        
        //update user table
        
        $sqlUpdate = "update users set currentPoints = currentPoints + ? where userID = ?";
        $Q = $this->db->query($sqlUpdate, array($data['amount'], $data['userID']));
        
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    function insert_data($data1)
        {
    
//         fund out
    
            $sql1 = "select * from transaction_ledger where userID = ?  order by ledgerID desc limit 0,1";
            $Q1 = $this->db->query($sql1, $data1['userID']);
    
            $R1 = $Q1->row_array();
            $ref= $this->session->userdata('userID') + time ();
    
            $idata1 = array(
                    'userID' => $data1['userID'],
                    'transactionSource' => 'FR',
                    'transType' => 'out',
                    'refNumber' => 'FO' . $ref,
                    'amount' => $data1['amount'],
                    'currentBalance' => $R1['currentBalance'] - $data1['amount'],
                    'previousBalance' => $R1['currentBalance'],
                    'remarks' => 'transfer fund to agent',
                );
    
            $this->db->insert('transaction_ledger', $idata1);
            
            $sqlUpdate = "update users set currentPoints = '".$idata1['currentBalance']."', dateUpdated = '".date('Y-m-d h:i:s')."'where userID = ?";
            
                    $this->db->query($sqlUpdate, $idata1['userID'] );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically open the bootstrap modal when document ready
Just like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#fundModal").modal('show');
});
</script>
```

I would suggest to do with ajax call for better user experience.

```
$( "#formId" ).on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let $form = $(this);
    $.post( 'post-url-here', $form.serialize(), function(result) {
        var result = JSON.parse(result);
        if( result.status == 'success' ) {
         $("#fundModal").modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello, is there a way where i can pass my input type textbox values  from my 1 modal to the onload modal? For example, I have this Form modal and i'm gonna pass it to my onload modal. Because that's what i'm targeting right now. Thank you.

Comment: I not understand your question but you can do something like `$('#modalId input').val( $('#form input').val())`